# How to handle select drop-down dynamically using mat-table in angular8?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, mat-table

I have to add columns dynamically to the mat-table, now I want to add some column rows are input fields, some are select drop-down and one is the output of all the columns. And these column names are dynamically.

How to handle those conditions in Mat-Table ?

Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg9fie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `displayedColumns` of `*matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">` dynamically and the table will re-render.

Just add a `formControl` to your `mat-selection-list` make your `displayedColumns` the value of it.

```
<mat-selection-list [formControl]="columnFormControl">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let column of ruleGroupColumns" [value]="column"></mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

```
ruleGroupColumns: string[] = [
  'MERGE',
  'FACILITY',
  'COMPANY'
];

columnFormControl = new FormControl(this.ruleGroupColumns);

get displayColumns() {
  return this.columnFormControl.value;
}
```